# Where are the GeoServer HTTP logs on Jetty server?

Tags: geoserver, google-cloud

I am trying to set up a load balanced cluster of GeoServers using Google Cloud, this requires setting a "health check". I'm trying to health check by doing an http get on /geoserver/web/ to load the main admin page for no other reason to see that the server is alive. Apparently this times out and fails. In trying to debug this, I can manually load `[server:port]/geoserver/web` but on the server side I do not see any HTTP access logs to see my manual access or the health check attempt access. I launch my server with the command

```
java [LIST OF OPTIONS] start.jar > log.txt
```

I can see startup information in `log.txt` and when I do WMS fetches those show up there too. But I don't see regular http accesses on the admin page. Where can I find/log those?

Comment: Don't use the jetty server (independent platform binary) in production it isn't set up to log things like http access. Use a proper servlet engine like tomcat

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton, I learned all about Tomcat and got that running and WOW does it render rasters faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetty does support logging http requests with the **requestlog module** since version 9.4.15 https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-jetty-request-logs.html. GeoServer 2.18 bin-zip contains Jetty version 9.4.18 so it is new enough for logging but the minimized Jetty that is packed into the zip does not contain the requestlog module and therefore it is not possible to enable http request logging.

I made test with a separate Jetty installation and managed it to gather request log this way:

1. Download Jetty version that has the request log module from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-distribution/9.4.29.v20200521/jetty-distribution-9.4.29.v20200521.zip.
2. Unzip Jetty.
3. Copy these directories from a working GeoServer bin-zip installation under new Jetty:

   - data_dir
   - webapps
   - bin
4. Switch to new Jetty directory and enable request logging as documented in https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-jetty-request-logs.html. I made it by editing the the existing startup line in the GeoServer startup.bat file this way `"%RUN_JAVA%" %JAVA_OPTS% -DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR="%GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR%" -Djava.awt.headless=true -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=geoserver -jar start.jar  --add-to-start=requestlog`. The important part is as documented just `java -jar ../start.jar --add-to-start=requestlog` but was feeling lazy and I knew that starup.bat is setting the paths etc. right so I reused it.
5. Run startup.bat once and then remove `--add-to-start=requestlog`.
6. Start GeoServer and see logs to appear into "logs" directory.

This is what appeared into the log after starting the layer preview for layer nurc:Pk50095

```
 "GET /geoserver/nurc/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=nurc%3APk50095&bbox=347649.93086859107%2C5176214.082539256%2C370725.976428591%2C5196961.352859256&width=768&height=690&srs=EPSG%3A32633&format=application/openlayers HTTP/1.1" 200 3954 
 "GET /geoserver/openlayers3/ol.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1115 
 "GET /geoserver/openlayers3/ol.js HTTP/1.1" 200 492313 
 "GET /geoserver/nurc/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=nurc%3APk50095&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A32633&STYLES=&WIDTH=769&HEIGHT=691&BBOX=344528.332252484%2C5173414.653827362%2C373862.563537699%2C5199771.178136721 HTTP/1.1" 200 41750 
 "GET /geoserver/nurc/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=nurc%3APk50095&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A32633&STYLES=&WIDTH=769&HEIGHT=691&BBOX=351861.8900737877%2C5180003.784904702%2C366529.0057163953%2C5193182.047059381 HTTP/1.1" 200 37057 
 "GET /geoserver/nurc/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=nurc%3APk50095&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A32633&STYLES=&WIDTH=769&HEIGHT=691&BBOX=355519.1250518247%2C5183288.806510757%2C362852.68287312845%2C5189877.937588097 HTTP/1.1" 200 31639
```